# C#: What does function expect as a IntPtr argument?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a tiny problem with a function from the µEye Framework, that expects parameter as follows in the framework description:

```
uEye.Memory.Allocate(int s32Width, int s32Height, int s32BitsPerPixel, System.IntPtr allocated, out int s32MemId)
```

I tried to invoke with the following code but it will fail:

```
int[] m_lSeqMemId = new int[MAX_SEQ_BUFFERS];           // camera memory - buffer ID
IntPtr[] m_pcSeqImgMem = new IntPtr[MAX_SEQ_BUFFERS];   // camera memory - pointer to buffer

m_Ret = MyCamera.Memory.Allocate(nAllocSizeX, nAllocSizeY, m_nBitsPerPixel, m_pcSeqImgMem[i], out m_lSeqMemId[i]);
```

-> ArgumentExeption.

I tried to translate from c++ but due to the difference of C/C++ and C#.net there are two completely different SDK which - who expected something else - have completely different naming conventions.

But, if it might help, the c++ code is as follows:

```
// header.h
INT     m_lSeqMemId[MAX_SEQ_BUFFERS];   // camera memory - buffer ID
char*   m_pcSeqImgMem[MAX_SEQ_BUFFERS]; // camera memory - pointer to buffer

// code.cpp
// allocate buffer memory
m_Ret = is_AllocImageMem(m_hCam,
                         nAllocSizeX,
                         nAllocSizeY,
                         m_nBitsPerPixel,
                         &m_pcSeqImgMem[i],
                         &m_lSeqMemId[i]);
```

I suppose I mess up with the reference/dereference but the compiler won't claim any errors?!

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: You may find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae(v=vs.110).aspx) interesting

Comment: Hi jack, thx for your answer.

I tried [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string[] m_pcSeqImgMem;   // camera memory - pointer to buffer but it didn't help. It's causing intellisence to assume I'm using a different overloaded function with another parameter list that doesn't fit my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The C# translation is wrong. The `IntPtr` parameter should be an `out parameter because the callee allocates a buffer and returns its address in that parameter. The parameters should be:

```
int s32Width, 
int s32Height, 
int s32BitsPerPixel,
out IntPtr allocated,
out int s32MemId
```

Call the function like this:

```
m_Ret = MyCamera.Memory.Allocate(
    nAllocSizeX,
    nAllocSizeY,
    m_nBitsPerPixel, 
    out m_pcSeqImgMem[i], 
    out m_lSeqMemId[i]
);
```

Comment: The function call is given by the .NET-Framework and not my translation. As I said the .NET and the c++ Version unfortunately do not have that much in common.

Comment: I don't think that this function is part of the .net framework. If you can't change the function definition you'll need to pin the IntPtr and pass its address.

Comment: Not by the framework, by the camera driver which is written in .NET

Comment: I don't think it is. It appears to be a p/invoke based wrapper around an unmanaged library.

Comment: Maybe - maybe not. I have no clue about it but I see, that it's not working. I suppose there might be two teams around this framework at IDS and one team doesn't know what's the other one's doing.

Comment: I've just answered based on what I can see. I've assumed that the C# code is meant to call the same function as the C# code. If that's not the case, then why is the C++ code here? Anyway, if you don't understand what this library is doing, and how to call it, you need to read the documentation once again, study the example code again, or contact the vendor.

Comment: As I said IDS is supplying two frameworks: One for .NET, one for C++. Both have the same functionality but due to language differences the invoke is different and moreover they have superfluously different function names... The C++ part works, the c# part not. I expect both frameworks to have the same idea behind the language and therefore I posted the c++ call to see, if there's some way to figure out, what might be wrong. Unfortunately there's no example code for c#, only for c++. Maybe they have a lack of trainees and therefore didn't implement the examples in c#. Sad for a 500$ VGA Camera.

Comment: What did the vendor say when you contacted them?